# Can't get a block of div tags to arrange themselves right

Tags: php, css, html, pixel

I'm using this block of code (mostly copied from a PHP.net comment here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) in order to read in a picture, scan it pixel by pixel and output the picture as a block of div tags in a table-like fashion.  Here's what I came up with...

```
<?php 
$img = imagecreatefrompng("image1.png"); 

$w = imagesx($img); 
$h = imagesy($img); 

for($y=0;$y<$h;$y++) { 
   for($x=0;$x<$w;$x++) { 
      $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y); 
      $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF; 
      $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF; 
      $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
      $hex = "#".str_repeat("0",2-strlen(dechex($r))).dechex($r). 
              str_repeat("0",2-strlen(dechex($g))).dechex($g). 
              str_repeat("0",2-strlen(dechex($b))).dechex($b);
     echo "<div style='background: {$hex}; height: 5px; width: 5px; display: inline;'></div>\r\n";
     /*
        echo "#".str_repeat("0",2-strlen(dechex($r))).dechex($r). 
              str_repeat("0",2-strlen(dechex($g))).dechex($g). 
              str_repeat("0",2-strlen(dechex($b))).dechex($b).","; 
     */ 
  } 
  echo "<br />\r\n"; 
} 
?>
```

I've tried using 'block', 'inline', 'inline-block' and 'inline-table' for the display property of the divs, but they each seem to make their own problems.  I either get nothing at all, columns of pixels going straight down in a vertical line or the divs line up correctly in a square, but with spacing between them (which shouldn't happen since I'm using a reset.css to eliminate all padding, spacing, etc).

Also, this particular function doesn't seem to account for transparency.  The picture I'm using has transparent pixels in it and it seems to be outputing them as a light blue.

Link - http://schnell.dreamhosters.com/folio/pixelread.php

Comment: I'd float the created `div` s in a larger parent `div` with a set width.

Comment: Ok, that worked to get them horizontally correct, but now I get rows of pixels separated vertically by a line of space.  Without the <br /> it becomes a single horizontal line of pixels and with the <br /> it becomes a line of pixels, a space, line of pixels, space, etc.

Comment: If this is a html/css problem, please add the html code generated by the php script (the 'view source' html for the relevant portion of the page).

Comment: Added a link to the page.  The actual markup generated is pretty long and redundant.

Comment: You can eliminate the ugly str_repeat/strlen stuff with `$hex = sprintf('%0X%0X%0X', $r, $g, $b)`

Comment: You don't need line breaks if you are able to calculate the width of the parent div.

Comment: @Marc B - I think that printf is missing something.  I'm using it and half the colors are coming up as white.  Apparently some of the color combinations are coming up as five digits instead of six.  I think colors that are '00' are being shortened to '0'.

Comment: Well, ain't that interesting. the 0-pad is ignored when printing hex characters with the printf() family. So... scratch my suggestion.

Comment: @Marc B - This might be a lucky stroke, but I managed to actually make it work by changing it to...    $hex = sprintf('#%02X%02X%02X', $r, $g, $b);  PS - I can't figure out how to make code blocks in comments.

Comment: @Mathias Use the backticks (\`) like you do in questions, like `this`

Comment: Yeah, that's it. %02X means pad with zeroes so it's 2 characters wide. My bad. *rubs eyes* long day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is an interesting one. I can't vouch for that function accounting for transparency, but the HTML positioning problem should be easy enough to solve.

I think the best solution would be to create a container as wide as the image, then float all of the `div`s left. Something like

```
echo "<div style='width: ".($imagesx * 5)."px;' class='outer'>";
```

Which will give the width you need (if I understand the code correctly). Then you simply use this CSS:

```
.outer div {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

Doing this will effectively reduce the number of redundant inline styles you have to generate. Oh, and remove the `br` generated after each row.

As for the alpha transparency problem, I believe this comment should help you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php#79116

---

**Edit**

You forgot the `px` on `width: 65px`! This is being generated.

```
<div style='width: 65; background: #eeeeee; margin: 0px auto;'>
```

Also, nice Mario. ;)

Comment: Ok, I pretty much did exactly this, but without a line break it's creating a long straight line of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<div style='background: {$hex}; height: 5px; width: 5px; position: absolute; top: {$y * 5}; left: {$x * 5};'></div>\r\n";
```

You'll want to place them all within a `position: relative;` containing element. And probably remove the `<br>`s too.

Comment: Yeah I know that's one solution and I've done it before with some other similar problems, but I was looking for one a little more fluid and less calculation involved.